# How to make my cam work from the network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding, camera

I have a 3com router [manual](http://adsl.aruba.it/manuali/3comOCWireless.pdf).

I have bought a wireless camera, and made it work. It is transmitting perfectly when connected to the router, as well as when acting on it's wireless mode.

I am now trying to access it from outside of my home.

I have a static IP. 
The camera has upnp option (what is it?)

In the router, in the Firewall section, I have created a Virtual Server, but when I access it from the web with: MYIP:82  I get an error.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my router firmware needed upgrade.

Once I did, everything works.

Comment: Thanks, I had to wait 24 hours to accept that. thank you